# What is a 'Brain State?'

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, neurophilosophy

I was recently reading on this, but found that a complete definition was vague.

What does a brain state mean?

Thanks!

Comment: This is really more of neuroscience question than a philosophical one. It might be more suitable for the biology board.

Comment: ["What is a Brain State?"](http://www.theassc.org/documents/what_is_a_brain_state)

Comment: While some neurophilosophers might say that a brain state is the actual "pattern" of active neurons, one could also consider the actual [pattern of active synapses](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/69689/models-of-the-brain-as-a-graph-and-another-neural-correlate-of-consciousness). (An active neuron being a neuron that just produced an action potential.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A brain state is a snapshot of everything in the central-nervous-system.

A brain state is said to contain everything about a person right the instant it is snapshotted: memories, emotions, skills, opinions, knowledge, etc.

Most importantly it is a snapshot of who you are *right that particular instant* the snapshot is taken.

If you buy into material/reductionist theories of consciousness, then a brain state is by necessity information about the physical constituents of the brain. If not, then substitute for a snapshot of whatever you believe a person's memories and opinions are made of, in order to understand the thought-experiment.